# Redirect article to 301 from directory redirected to 410

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have redirected directory to 410 in `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 410 /books/videos/
```

Now I want to write a rule to redirect some articles from /books/videos/ to 301 page. I tried it as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/books/videos/how-to-find-videos.html /books/how-to-find-videos.html [L,R=301]
```

When I visit `www.mysite.com/books/videos/how-to-find-videos.html` it shows me 410 gone page. That means 301 rule is not getting applied here. How can I achive `410 and 301` for same directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` directives that are from different Apache modules.

Have it like this in given order:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific files are redirected with 301
RewriteRule ^/?books/videos/how-to-find-videos\.html$ /books/how-to-find-videos.html [L,R=301,NC]

# remaining URIs from this path to get 410
RewriteRule ^/?books/videos/ - [L,R=410]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.